# image insert to SQL Server varbinary(max) gets truncated to 8kb

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, varbinary

I'm trying to upload high resolution images though pyodbc 4.0.30 to my database using a filestream.

```
INSERT INTO images(id, imageFile)
   SELECT NEWID(), BulkColumn
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'd:/tmp/20150627_132729.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as f;
```

This code uploads images that can be retrieved perfectly.

But when I try the same thing through pyodbc with the code below, the images are always 8 KB max, so only a piece appears on my ASP.NET webform.

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

with open(imgPath, 'rb') as f:
     bindata = f.read()

cursor.execute("insert into images(id, imageFile) values (NEWID(), ?)", (pyodbc.Binary(bindata)))

cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Spent a long time researching. I guess I have to somehow execute bulk insert but for that the file needs to be on the database machine while I am trying to insert from raspberry pi.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Which ODBC driver are you using? Please [edit] your question to include its name and version.

Comment: pyodbc 4.0.30 python3  is the module that i am using

Comment: To work with pyodbc you need to use an ODBC driver. It's most likely to be either Microsoft's ODBC driver or the FreeTDS ODBC driver. Which is it?

Comment: I am using FreeTDS right now.

Comment: Use [check_tds_protocol_version](https://github.com/gordthompson/check_tds_protocol_version) to see which version of the TDS protocol you are using. What does it report?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/tdsVersionCheck.py", line 36, in <module>
    ).format(os.environ['myUID'], os.environ['myPWD'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'myUID'

I get that error when run the code

Comment: I think its the "with open" command that's unable to hold more than 8kb because I am able to insert full size images through c#.

Comment: The `__main__` code in check_tds_protocol_version is just an example. If you want to use it you'll need to edit it to use values applicable to your particular circumstances.